# RDLC - xml generation report - Error More than one dataset, data region, or grouping in the report has the name DataTable1

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset, rdlc

I was trying to create an RDLC with xml string generated dynamically.
I tried to fix this exception but no progress.
The problem is that my report is a big `<Tablix>` and inside this Tablix there is another Tablix that contains my returned data.
I created the Dataset with this:

```
DynamicSO dsSOPaymentReport = new DynamicSO();
dsSOPaymentReport.DataSetName = "DynamicSO";
DataTable soPaymentTable = new DataTable("dtDataTable1");
```

DynamicSO is an empty .xsd and I am filling it in the code.

Here I am generating the xml string.

```
string xmlstring = reportDynamic.GenerateReport(ref reportBuilder);
```

And here it is the issue I have 2 Tablixes inisde each other but it is giving me the Exception as i mentioned

**`More than one dataset, data region, or grouping in the report has the name DataTable1 Dataset, data region, and grouping names must be unique within a report.`**

Comment: A RDLC file is HTML not XML.  You can't interchange Xml and HTML.  They are similar but not the same.  HTML (RDLC) has special characters that have to be substituted.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: bro rdlc is xml , why u keep arguing about this while my error is something else

Comment: Does you server have more than one database?  If so you have to include the database before the table name.

Comment: what do u mean please clarify

Comment: A SQL Server can have more than one Database attached.

Comment: only one Database exists